# Cleanly remove bower from an ASP.Net 5 project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bower, asp.net-core

I'm using the ASP.Net 5 RC, but I don't want to use bower, I want to use NPM to manage all of my dependencies.

I have removed **bower.json**, removed the *bower install* command from **project.json** and specifically removed each package using *bower uninstall*.

However, it stil shows up in the solution explorer:

[image: Solution Explorer, with bower still present]

Is there any way to properly remove it, or is this just the way ASP.Net 5 is supposed to be used?

Thanks

Comment: In general `bower` is not bad. It can be for example, that you need to use some component, which are published on `bower`, but not published on `npm`. I find just not good the default content of `.bowerrc` file `{"directory": "wwwroot/lib"}` which informs Visual Studio place all the files from the package installed by `bower` directly in `wwwroot/lib`. One can change the content to `{"directory": "bower_components"}` and to have the same behavior as with `npm`. One can then use `grunt` for example for building the `wwwroot` content.

Comment: See [the post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ControlHowYourBowerPackagesAreInstalledWithAGulpfileInASPNET5.aspx) for more details.

Comment: @Oleg, I have read that before, however why not just use npm to manage all dependencies? Surely one package manager is better than two?

Comment: I mention the reason shortly before. Bower repository and nmp repositories are **two different repositories**, where JavaScript packages could be found now. One have to publish *separately* in both repositories. I started with bower in my first ASP.NET project, but I could not found Angular2 in bower repository (only angular 1.4.x). there are exist event separate GitHub repository `https://github.com/angular/bower-angular`. I have to use `npm`. In the same way I found another examples where the package was published only in `bower` (I can give you examples if you want).

Comment: If one uses tools like `grunt` then **one need just have the files locally** and one makes the copy to `wwwroot` as the build task. Thus I decide just use `.bowerrc` file with `{"directory": "bower_components"}` for me and to get the packages from any source, where I could find there. I can copy the data from `bower_components` directory in the same way like I copy the data from `node_modules`. Npm is my personal favor and I read that `bower` development could be stopped soon. Nevertheless I prefer to hold both options opened. I publish my components in both repositories.

Comment: Cool, good info, thanks

Comment: [Bower is dying](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1074) tho and `npm3` may be the way forward

Comment: @Dealdiane Yeah that's the impression I have too. Any idea why it's a default tool in the new Asp.net?

Comment: @JMK No idea. Just found out today lol. I guess because the aspnet team is more of a _backend_ than a _frontend_ people. Based on the last aspnet community standup, it looks like they  _might_ move to npm3 for rc2 but not sure whether they'd ditch bower.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out, the key is to remove the **DnxInvisibleContent** tag inside **ItemGroup** in the xproj file.

My **ItemGroup** section now looks like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include=".bowerrc" />
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include="package.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. There was an empty `Bower` folder under the `Dependancis` folder that appeared with the yellow exclamation symbol. There was no option to delete it by right-clicking and selecting the context menu. But there was a folder named `bower_component` inside the project folder. This was excluded from the project in solution explorer, so it will only show if the `Show All files` button is ticked. Deleting this folder automatically removed the `Bower` folder located under the the`Dependancies` node.