# MVC6 How to remove bower from project

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, bower

I want to create a single page application by using ASP.NET Core, MVC6 and react.js.
My idea is to use only one MVC controller to render the initial html. I include react.js via npm so bower will not be used and I would like to completely remove it from this project, but I can't find how.

I remove it from anywhere but I can still see it:

[image]

Any suggestion on how to remove it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cleanly remove bower from an ASP.Net 5 project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342909/cleanly-remove-bower-from-an-asp-net-5-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [bower is integrated with VS IDE](http://webtooling.visualstudio.com/package-managers/bower/).

However if you don't need/want bower libs in your project just clear content of `bower.json` and save it or you can go `Manage Bower Package` and uninstall all, after that bower will have no impact on your project.

*I'm not sure if removing of `bower.json` file will also remove all libs form project/disk.*

**Update:**

I found way to remove Bower and NPM dependencies from ASP.NET Core projects...

**It's not documented, so I can't recommended it!**

In your `*.xproj` file you can find something like that:

```
<ItemGroup> 
   <DnxInvisibleContent Include="bower.json" /> 
   <DnxInvisibleContent Include=".bowerrc" /> 
   <DnxInvisibleContent Include="package.json" /> 
   <DnxInvisibleContent Include=".npmrc" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

If you remove appropriate lines from this files, then Bower or/and NPM will be removed form your project.

This will not delete files automatically from disk, so you need clean up your project manually - remove:

- `lib` folder (in `wwwroot`), `bower.json` and `.bowerrc` files,
- `npm_module` folder, `package.json` and `npmrc` files,
- `gulpfile.js` (and other files related to NPN packages if any),

*I hope this will help you.*

Comment: @monkeydeveloper  I found way to remove Bower and NPM dependencies from ASP.NET Core projects ;) Read updated answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

For .NET Core 2.0, as I did a scaffolding inside a WebAPI project, it turned out I could simply remove "bower_components" folder in the project root and it did the trick for me. This alongside removing any references to bower dependencies (jquery, etc) in any config file

Comment: Even after removing all packages from the bower.json file or deleting bower.json itself, the Bower node in Solution Explorer probably remains visible. Click Show All Files in Solution Explorer to see bower_components and deleting this as rjso suggests gets rid of the Bower node.

Comment: Same here.  VS is incredibly buggy and brittle.  Lot's of wizbang UI features that turnout to be completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using npm, simply `npm uninstall bower` in your project directory after having installed and/or you can specify in your package.json what modules you need and then run npm install, if bower was added, just uninstall it as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer doesn't work.  As Darren Evans commented, even after removing all packages from bower.json file and the .json file itself, the Bower node is visible when you click Show All Files in the Solution Explorer Window. You will also see a "bower_components" folder and if you delete that as well, Bower will still linger in your system.

Bower isn't "integrated" with VS, meaning part of the core VS. To permanently rid your solution of bower, do everything suggested, but delete all references from the .VS folder as well.